# Symfony2, Swagger 2 and Bundle TimeIncOSS swagger-bundle error

Tags: symfony, swagger, swagger-2.0

I work with symfony project and i want to generate documentation for my **REST Web Service** with **swagger 2**,so i installed [**swagger-bundle**](https://github.com/TimeIncOSS/swagger-bundle)
and i configurid it.but when i tri to generate the json api documenation with this command

```
app/console -e=dev swagger:dump
```

i got this error.

> You must call one of in() or append() methods before iterating over a
>   Finder.

this is my config file

```
swagger:
    version: '2.0'
    info:
        title: 'My API'
        version: '1.0.0'
        description: 'My API Description'
    host: '127.0.0.1'
    base_path: '/v2'
    schemes:
        - http
    produces:
        - application/json
    consumes:
        - application/json
    annotations:
        bundles:
            - BOBundleBundle
```

any help please.

Answer (score -1):

check if you put the settings in the correct config file (app/config/config_dev.yml)